# Probability Distribution help, I'm stuck and can't find out how to get forward.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions

The DMV hires a consultant to do something about all their complaints for wait times. They find that $75\%$ of their visitors get through the line in less than $20$ minutes. If the standard deviation of the wait time is $6.2$ minutes, find the average wait time per visitor.

I got somewhat close where I lined up the equation but I got stuck somewhere and don't know how to solve it, I'll take any answers.

The point where I had gotten to was labelling the probability as $P(X<20)=.75$
I then had the formula rearranged to be as $(20-μ)/6.2)=c$ and I believe $C=.75$ but not entirely sure that's correct either.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far? Please edit your query to show your attempts.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have enough informantion to answer the question. Are you sure this is all you got? Did they give you the distribution of wait times?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far could you get? Where are you stuck? This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by editing the question body. Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: @chuck in this question, yes this was all that I was given.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see how. Your formula is standardizing the wait time and that is usually something to do with normal distribution

Answer (score 1):

The problem cannot be solved as stated.  If we add the assumption that the wait times are normally distributed, then $x=20$ corresponds to $P=0.75$. Using either a table, software, or a TI-83 calculator (my choice, I just use "DISTR" aka "Shift-VARS" to get distributions, scroll down to 3:invNorm, press ENTER, put in $.75$),  we get $Z = 0.674489$.  Then from $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} = Z$ we plug in $x, \sigma,$ and $Z$, and solve to get $15.8$ minutes for the mean.

Remember that you are dealing with three kinds of numbers: $x$ (minutes), $Z$ (how many standard deviations you are above the mean), and $P$ probability, which equals the area under the curve for the probability density function (the bell curve in this case).  You switch between $x$ and $Z$ using the algebra formula, and you switch between $Z$ and $P$ using a table or software or calculator.  Always bear in mind what kind of number you have. If it has units, it is an $x$.  If it is a number with no units but is commonly between $-2$ and $2$, it is likely a $Z$.  If it is a decimal between $0$ and $1$, it is likely a probability.  The ambiguity is that $Z$ is sometimes between $0$ and $1$ as well.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one answer. Say that the distribution of wait times is discrete with one point mass less than 20 and one more than 20. Say there is .75 chance that the person waits 10 minutes and a .25 chance that the person waits x minutes with x > 20. We need 2 things to hold, namely (1) the standard deviation is 6.1 minutes and (2) the cdf at 20 is .75. The second condition is satisfied, thus we must simply find x such that condition (1) is satisfied. This can be found by solving for x in the equation $V(X)=E\left[(X-\bar X)^2\right]$ with $X$ being the wait time; this translates to $6.1^2=.75(10-(10*.75+x*.25))^2+.25(x-(10*.75+x*.25))^2$, giving $x=24.09$ and an expected value of $E(X)=.75(10)+.25(24.09)=13.52$.

Consider now that there isa  .75 chance that the person waits 19 minutes and a .25 chance that the person waits x minutes, x>20. Solving for x in $6.1^2=.75(19-(19*.75+x*.25))^2+.25(x-(19*.75+x*.25))^2$ gives $x=33.09$ and $E(X)=.75(10)+.25(33.09)=15.77$.